# How can you pull option values from a modal into a form with PHP and HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can you pull data from the data-mylink from bootstrap into a modal form or do I have to do that with a PHP string like I have done?    I know how to do this with JQuery(you may notice with the code), but want to know how to do this with PHP and HTML.  I have limited use of javascript in a particular environment, so I need to learn it this way.

PHP and HTML:

```
$rowaudit1=$row[auditID];
<button type='button' id='print_audit' 
 data-mylink=\"<?php $rowaudit1 ?>\"
                    class='btn btn-default btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#print_audit_form' value='Print'>Print</button>
```

I pull the $rowaudit1 into the modal with php, then the Modal part is what confuses me on how to pull in the option values into a form:

```
<div class="modal" id="print_audit_form" style="z-index:10000" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">
            Printing Options</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                    <td>
                        Filename: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="print_name" 
                        name="print_name" /><br/><br/>
                        Orientation: <select name="print_orient" id="print_orient">
                                        <option value="portrait">Portrait</option>
                                        <option value="landscape">Landscape</option>
                                    </select><BR/><BR/>
                        View Options: <select name="download_option" id="download_option">
                                        <option value="0">Display</option>
                                        <option value="1">Download</option>
                                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>Enter the filename for Downloading(optional), orientation, and if you want to view or download the audit.</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>

                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form role="form" action='print_audit.php?auditID="<?php $rowaudit1 ?>"&action=print&print_name="+print_name+"&print_orient="+print_orient+"&download_option="+download_option+"&type="+value' method="get" >
                    <div class="form-group">
```

when I click this form button is there a way to put that value into the action - &type="+value ?

```
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="print_audit_form_button" value="PDF"/>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="print_audit_form_button_web" value="Web"/>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery I am trying to wean off of to learn it the PHP HTML route:

```
$('#print_audit_form').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var auditID = btn.data('mylink');
    $("#print_audit_form_button").click(function(){

                 var print_name = $("#print_name").val();

                 var print_orient=$("#print_orient").val();
                 var download_option=$("#download_option").val();
                //alert(auditID+print_name+print_orient+download_option);

                window.open("print_audit.php?auditID="+auditID+"&action=print&print_name="+print_name+"&print_orient="+print_orient+"&download_option="+download_option+"&type=pdf");

                 //window.location.reload(true);
                return false; 
            });
         });
```

Comment: `java` has nothing to do with `javascript`.

Comment: My error,  I meant to write javascript in there.  Just edited it.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to pull form <options> into a Get action?

Comment: you can stuff anything you want into a query string, and you can extract anything you want from the DOM, so... yes.

Comment: Should it be put into Action , or is there a better way with inputs?